# Looping within const in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

This is really minimal... but I haven't been able to figure this out.

```
  const compose_url = (id, key) =>
   `${id}/image/_/${key}`;


  const get_images = compose_url(
    this.props.dataset_id, // pass in prefix (2018_1_25)
    get_image_arrays // This returns an array with two arrays e.g. [["img1.png"], ["img2.png"]]
  );
```

I want this to return "2018_1-25/img1.png" and "2018_1-25/img2.png", but I'm only getting that for the first array, ("2018_1-25/img1.png") not for the second one. How could I loop through this to add the prefix to both images?

Please help... I haven't found documentation or examples on how to do this.

Comment: What does compose_url() do? what are you expecting in get_images variable?

Comment: @mindaJalaj `compose_url()` is a function that takes in two parameters to compose a URL (dataset_id, image_key) =>
    ${dataset_id}/image/_/${image_key}; ` In this case, I want `get_images` to add the first parameter to both arrays... not just one

Comment: get_image_arrays are always separated array like two array ` ["img1.png"] ["img2.png"]` three array ` ["img1.png"] ["img2.png"]  ["img2.png"]`. is it? Please, console your get_image_arrays before passing and edit your question with the console data.

Comment: why is it an array with a single string in it?

Comment: Sorry... correction it's an array with two arrays inside: [["img1.png"], ["img2.png"]]. I corrected my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
const compose_url = (id, arr) => {
  return arr.map((ar) => (
    `${id}/image/_/${ar}`
  ));
};
```

This function will return `[ "2018_1_25/image/_/img1.png", "2018_1_25/image/_/img2.png" ]`

Answer (score 1):

```
const get_images = [];
const { dataset_id: id } = this.props;

get_images_array.forEach(arr => {
  arr.forEach(path => {
    get_images.push(
      compose_url(
        id,
        path
      )
    );
  }
});
```

EDIT:

I took a different approach to other answers and instead of modifying the `compose_url` method, I worked off of the the given data. This approach iterates over the top level array (`get_images_array`) and then iterates over each of the arrays in `get_images_array`. For each path in the inner arrays, the result of `compose_url` is pushed onto the `get_images` result array.

Comment: Could you please comment on how the solution works? Posting the code only does not amount to an answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to update compose_url() function here, and make sure you always pass array as second of the vairable.

```
const compose_url = (date, imageArray) => 
    imageArray.map((eachImage) => `${id}/image/_/${eachImage}`);
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply map over the array like

```
const compose_url = (id, arr) => {
    return [].concat(arr.map(data => [].concat(data.map(key) => `${id}/${key}`)));
}



 const get_images = compose_url(
    this.props.dataset_id, // pass in prefix (2018_1_25)
    get_image_arrays // This returns an array with two arrays e.g. [["img1.png"], ["img2.png"]]
  );
```